# Google Form / Script: How to redirect the uploaded files to different folders depending on the drop-down choice

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Does anyone know if I can automatically (I guess with a help of Google Script) redirect the uploeaded files to different folders depending on the choice the user makes in previous question with drop-down list?

Let's say if he chooses 'Meat', then the file goes to folder called 'Meat', if he chooses 'Fish', then to the folder 'Fish' etc.
I cannot find any examples of script for this.

Comment: Yep, can certainly be done. You'll have to wear your programmer hat and write code, as is expected of anyone who posts on Stack Overflow. Write an `on form submit` trigger function that reads the items in the response and then changes the `parents` of the uploaded file. If you encounter some specific error or trouble after starting your script, then post your specific question and your MCVE.

Comment: @AdiMabfalin Which part of my question is suggesting this? I asked if this is possible at all. I am not expecting anyone to do it for me, so pelase leave your assumptions for yourself. I am not a programmer, but I thought this is a place where I can ask a question if sth can be done.

Comment: @tehhowch Thank you for your response, I will follow your advices